# Can I use Mercurial to allow different users access to different parts of a project?

Tags: mercurial

We're using SVN, but it seems to be getting a little out of date and heavy for our liking. We have a big project that we need different team members to get access to different parts of. Can we set up Mercurial is a way that certain people can checkout / update the entire project, where as some other people only check out / access certain parts of the project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's the [ACL](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/AclExtension) extension which is shipped as part of Mercurial that may be suitable for your needs.

Answer (score 4):

My initial thought is that it could be done using subrepos.  If you can split your project into defined parts, these could be set up as sub-repositories.  You would have a parent repository which contains all of the sub-repositories.  The sub-repositories themselves could be set up to be accessible only by certain people.